# Store is not updated in redux, even when the reducer is returning new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image]

I am new to learning react and redux, I was designing a to-do list app (having two level nesting) and came across a problem. 
So this is how my output looks on screen as in the picture, the motto here is that when I click on any 'x' , the corresponding element will be deleted, the state updates and the UI is re-rendered. 
The data within red boxes are (say like children to the ones above it) i.e., : Work, Sketch, Gym, Dinner are parent level elements and the data within red boxes are next-level data.

When I delete work/sketch/gym/dinner they work fine, but i try to delete any of the nested elements, it doesn't work. Is it because I am deleting nested data?

This is my code: can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

src/App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Wrapper from './components/wrapper'
import store from './redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
          <div className="App">
            <Wrapper />
          </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}



export default App;
```

src/components/childComponent.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import {addChildEelem, deleteChildElem} from '../redux/actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
    render() {
        if(this.props.displayChild) {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                <input id="second-input"/>
                <button id="second-button">Add</button>
                <div className="second_level_cards">
                    {
                        this.props.data.map((elem) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="second_level_card">
                                <li id={elem.list_id}>
                                    {elem.list_content}
                                </li>
                                <span 
                                    className="close"
                                    onClick={this.props.deleteChildEelem_}>
                                    X
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                </Fragment>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div></div>
            )
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        fullData_ : state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addChildEelem_ : (e) => dispatch(addChildEelem(e)),
        deleteChildEelem_ : (e) => dispatch(deleteChildElem(e))
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildComponent);
```

src/component/parentComponent.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import '../App.css'
import ChildComponent from './childComponent'
import {addFirstLevelElem, deleteFirstLevelElem, addChildEelem, deleteChildElem} from '../redux/actions'

class parentElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {displayChild: true}
    }
    displaychildHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            displayChild: !this.state.displayChild
        })
    }
    render() {
        const {displayChild} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="first_level_card">
                    <div className="parent">
                        <li className="flcc" id={this.props.data.list_id} onClick={this.displaychildHandler}>
                            {this.props.data.list_content}
                        </li>
                        <span 
                            className="flcc close"
                            onClick={this.props.deleteFirstLevelElem_}
                        >X</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="child">
                        <ChildComponent 
                                    displayChild={displayChild}
                                    data={this.props.data.list_children}
                        />
                            {/* <input id="second-input"/>
                            <button id="second-button">Add</button>
                            <div className="second_level_cards"> 
                                {
                                    this.props.data.list_children.map((elem) => {
                                        return (
                                            <div className="second_level_card">
                                                <li id={elem.list_id}>
                                                    {elem.list_content}
                                                </li>
                                                <span 
                                                    className="close"
                                                    onClick={this.props.deleteChildEelem_}>
                                                    X
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }

                            </div>
                             */}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        fullUsers : state
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      addFirstLevelElem_: (e) => dispatch(addFirstLevelElem(e)),
      deleteFirstLevelElem_: (e) => dispatch(deleteFirstLevelElem(e)),
      addChildEelem_ : (e) => dispatch(addChildEelem(e)),
      deleteChildEelem_ : (e) => dispatch(deleteChildElem(e))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(parentElement);
```

src/component/wrapper.js :

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import ParentElement from './parentComponent'
import {addFirstLevelElem, deleteFirstLevelElem, addChildEelem, deleteChildElem} from '../redux/actions'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Fragment>
            <input id='input' />
            <button id='button'>Add</button>
            {
            this.props.fullData_.map(
                (elem) => {
                    return (
                        <ParentElement 
                            data={elem}
                        />
                    )
                }
            )
            }
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        fullData_ : state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Wrapper);
```

src/redux/actions.js :

```
import {ADD_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM,
        DELETE_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM,
        ADD_CHILD_ELEM,
        DELETE_CHILD_ELEM
        } from './constTypes';

export const addFirstLevelElem = (data) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM,
        payload: data
    }
}

export const deleteFirstLevelElem = (data) => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM,
        payload: data
    }
}

export const addChildEelem = (data) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_CHILD_ELEM,
        payload: data
    }
}

export const deleteChildElem = (data) => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_CHILD_ELEM,
        payload: data
    }
}
```

src/redux/constTypes.js :

```
export const ADD_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM = "ADD_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM";
export const DELETE_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM = "DELETE_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM";
export const ADD_CHILD_ELEM = "ADD_CHILD_ELEM";
export const DELETE_CHILD_ELEM = "DELETE_CHILD_ELEM";
```

src/redux/reducer.js :

```
import {
        ADD_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM,
        DELETE_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM,
        ADD_CHILD_ELEM,
        DELETE_CHILD_ELEM
        } from './constTypes';

import fullData from '../data';

const initialState = fullData;

let constReturnValue;

const addFirstLevelElement = (e, stateList) => {
    console.log(e, stateList);
}

const deleteFirstLevelElement = (e, stateList) => {
    let deleteElemId = e.target.previousElementSibling.id;
    let newList = stateList.filter((elem) => elem.list_id != deleteElemId )
    return newList;
}

const addChildElement = (e, stateList) => {
    console.log(e, stateList);
}

const deleteChildElement = (e, stateList) => {
    let elemToBeDeletedId = e.target.previousElementSibling.id;
    let parentHierarchy = e.target.previousElementSibling.id[0];
    let parentId = `first_card_${parentHierarchy}`;
    let newChildList, newList = stateList;
    for(let i=0; i<newList.length; i++) {
        if(newList[i].list_id == parentId) {
            newChildList =  newList[i].list_children.filter((elem) => elem.list_id != elemToBeDeletedId)
            newList[i].list_children = newChildList
        } 
    }
    return newList;
}

export const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM:
            constReturnValue = addFirstLevelElement(action.payload, state);
            return constReturnValue
        case DELETE_FIRST_LEVEL_ELEM: 
            constReturnValue = deleteFirstLevelElement(action.payload, state);
            return constReturnValue;
        case ADD_CHILD_ELEM: 
            constReturnValue = addChildElement(action.payload, state);
            return constReturnValue;
        case DELETE_CHILD_ELEM: 
            constReturnValue = deleteChildElement(action.payload, state);
            return constReturnValue;
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

src/redux/store.js

```
import { createStore} from 'redux';
import {reducer} from './reducer'

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

src/data.js :

```
const ListData = [
    {
        list_id: "first_card_1",
        list_content: "Work",
        list_state: "pending",
        list_children: 
                        [
                            {
                                list_id: "1_card_child_1",
                                list_content: "Have breakfast",
                                list_state: "pending",
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "1_card_child_2",
                                list_content: "Keep wallet and ID card",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "1_card_child_3",
                                list_content: "Book a cab",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "1_card_child_4",
                                list_content: "Reached office",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            }   
                        ]

    },
    {
        list_id: "first_card_2",
        list_content: "Sketch",
        list_state: "pending",
        list_children: 
                        [
                            {
                                list_id: "2_card_child_1",
                                list_content: "Charge ipad and pencil",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "2_card_child_2",
                                list_content: "List down ideas meanwhile",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "2_card_child_3",
                                list_content: "start execution",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "2_card_child_4",
                                list_content: "Mark Done",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                        ]
    },
    {
        list_id: "first_card_3",
        list_content: "Gym",
        list_state: "pending",
        list_children: 
                        [
                            {
                                list_id: "3_card_child_1",
                                list_content: "Keep extra clothes",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            }
                        ]
    },
    {
        list_id: "first_card_4",
        list_content: "Dinner",
        list_state: "pending",
        list_children: 
                        [
                            {
                                list_id: "4_card_child_1",
                                list_content: "Buy groceries",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },
                            {
                                list_id: "4_card_child_2",
                                list_content: "Call Cook",
                                list_state: "pending"
                            },    
                        ]
    },
]

export default ListData;
```

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you put your code in f.eks, https://codesandbox.io/ so that it will be easy to go through your code rather than read so many lines of plain code here!

Comment: I don't have anything definitive, but a couple of thoughts as to what could be the problem: 1: `let newChildList, newList = stateList;` `newChildList` and `newList` should be clones of `stateList` not assigned `stateList` directly. 2: `let constReturnValue;
` seems like it should be declared in each case statement, not at the top of the file.

Comment: @ZekeHernandez you are right, I just realised that a while ago while going through my code. I should actually be returning a new object which is clone of stateList and not change the stateList itself. I was going to comment here, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: @curious.netter problem solved :) thanks anyways :)